# Do the matrices $S^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu]$ have a name?

Tags: terminology, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-matrices

Do the matrices $S^{\mu\nu}$ defined by

$$
S^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu]
$$

have a name ($\gamma^\mu$ are the gamma matrices)? They feel very important to me since they form a representation of the Lorentz algebra, so I would like to know if there's an accepted name for them in the literature. If there's none, what would you name them?

Answer (score 1):

These are the generators of Lorentz transformations, see Peskin and Schroeder, pg. 41. $S^{ij}$ are rotation generators, and $S^{0i}$ are the boost generators.

Comment: I think he/she is aware of that and is after the name

Comment: @Akoben, you're correct. This answer isn't very useful to me because I already know what the $S^{\mu\nu}$ are, I just want to know if they are commonly referred to by some term.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it called the spin tensor or spin matrix.

Comment: Any sources? (e.g., published lecture notes, journal articles, books) Or is it just something a professor said once?

Comment: While spin matrix makes sense, it's a problematic term since the Pauli and gamma matrices are often called spin matrices as well.